# Select rows from a table if one of them matches with another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

- product
- movement
- movement_product

The `product` table has a field `group_id` (is the product's group).
The `movement_product` table has a field `movement_id` (matches with `movement` table) and `product_id` (matches with the `product` table).

I want to select all the movement products of a movement if one of them is from a specific group of products.

I tried the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    mp.*
FROM
    movement AS m,
    movement_product AS mp
WHERE
    m.id = mp.movement_id
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM product p
        WHERE mp.product_id = p.id
        AND p.group_id = "48"
    )
GROUP BY mp.movement_id
```

But it is returning a list just with the products that are from that specific group (the 48 on group_id is just an example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can follow this logic.  First, to get all the movements that qualify:

```
select distinct mp.movement_id
from movement_products mp
where exists (select 1
              from products p
              where p.id = mp.product_id and
                    p.group_id = 48
             );
```

To get the products in these movements, you can do:

```
select mp.*
from movement_products mp
where mp.movement_id in (select mp.movement_id
                         from movement_products mp
                         where exists (select 1
                                       from products p
                                       where p.id = mp.product_id and
                                       p.group_id = 48
                        );
```